# Automatic serialization

Tags: vb.net, serialization, xsd

I want to download xsd specifications from a web service and automatic converting (serialize) these schemas to classes (visual studio - vb.net). If the organization that is responsible for the xsd schemas alter them in a way that only my class corresponding to the xsd have to be altered (not the rest of my code) I would like to automatic update my xsd corresponding class. Is this possible? If so, can somebody tell me how to do it?

Thanks!

I use vs2010. What I want to do is: call a web service where I can send in an input parameter to the service which specifies the xsd I want to retrieve (the service is GetShemaDefenition and returns an object with the schema specification in a string property of the object). I den have to read the xsd string from the string property and convert this to a class representation of this xsd specification. Is it possible to do this automatically? I have done this manually by using xsd.exe. If the owner organization of the xsd has altered the xsd specification, I have to test if there is a new specification, and if there is I have to build a new class representation of this xsd? Is it possible to do what I want? And how would I know if it has been a big change in the xsd which also affect other parts of my code, not just the class representation of the xsd?

Tanks a lot for your reply! So what you are saying, if I understand you correct, is that there is not a good solution for automating this functionality because if the xsd change I most likely (in some occasions’) have to change my code manually? So I have to choose, either in my application or in my intermediate service? But what is the purpose for providing the xsd in a web service? What can I use the web service for? I just wondering, maybe it is clear but I am new to web services and is eager to learn more.

**Update:**

Thanks! But can you explain a little bit more. What I have to do is: I use one web service where one of the properties is a string. The string is an XML inside a CDATA block. The organization which provides the web service will not pares the xml inside the CDATA block but instead forward this to another organization that will use the xml data. The organization which uses the xml data specifies the xsd schem that I have to follow to generate my xml correct. This is the xsd schema I can get from another web service. I don’t really understand what I can do with this xsd file from the web service. What can I do with it and why do I want to download it from the web service, when I can’t use it automatically? Because I have to manually do the changes when the xsd changes I can easily download the xsd schema from the organization’s home page and make the new class with xsd.exe. I understand there is something I don’t understand :o), can you pleas clarify?

Comment: The schema is there so that you know the interface for the server. It's like a contract between the provider and the consumer. This contract (interface, and the xsd that describes it.) are supposed to be stable and the provider of the service is not expected to change it often.Professional service provider will take the necessary effort to keep the interface backward compatible in case of a change. That said nothing can stop them from changing it.

Answer (score 0):

What visual studio version you are using?, Normally you can click on the project's references and Add Web service. In this case Visual studio creates automatically the objects required to consume the service. you can update it any time by a right click on the reference.

However if it is very likely to change often, One solution is to implement an adapter class. use create an interface that provides the same functionality and call the actual web service. In your application you use only the proxy class and not the Web Service. Later when the web service interface changes all you have to do is to change the internals of this intermediate class.

Update:

you can use [this tool](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2007/01/writing-your-own-xsdexe.html) to create you object model in code. Then you can [compile your new object model](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cscompiler.aspx) and use it in you application. There are many complications in what you want to do and the bottom line is; when the object model changes, your code will fail. There is absolutely no way to imagine how the interface will change so while you can do all that automatically there is nothing to do if the name of a function changes.

However the answer to your situation is indirection. If you can't guaranty the stability of a external service. Why not create a stable intermediate service that calls the actual one? this way in future you don't need to touch you application. All you have to do is to modify the intermediate service while keeping it's interface compatible.

Comment: I have to post a comment as a new question.